# Unable to submit form with dropdown menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Alright so this has been bothering me for a while. I'm trying to create a system that will keep track of points. The first thing to appear on the page is a dropdown menu, from which you can select a group. This group matches a group that can be found in the database. Upon selecting one of these groups, the group members will show up in a table. This table has several columns, each (besides the name column) contains a checkbox. After clicking on one (or several) of these checkboxes, and submitting the form, I would like to have the points corresponding to those checkboxes added to the database, and the same group of people show up (So all checkboxes should be cleared, and dropdown menu should still have the same value).

Ajax is probably the best way to handle this, but unfortunately, I haven't got any experience using Ajax, so therefore I'm just using php with some javascript. I'll try to post as few bits of coding as possible.

This creates the dropdown menu:

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"page.php">";
echo "</br><select name=\"squad\" id=\"squad\" onchange=\"changeSquad(this.value)\">";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<option value='". $row['squad_id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";   
  }
echo "</select>";
```

Function changeSquad() then opens the file where the data is requested & table is created:

```
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
    $length=0;    
     echo "<table id='form'><tr>
     <td>Member</td>
     <td>1st box</td>
     </tr>";
require 'nextfile.php';
}
```

This 'nextfile.php' contains most of the checkbox handling, setting points to them, adding that data to the database, etc. The most important thing it does:

```
echo "</form><tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' /></td></tr>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
-- Do all updates --
echo "<script> alert('Points have been updated!'); </script>";
}
```

I've already tried adding this right after the submit button:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submitted\" id=\"submitted\" value=\"true\" />";
```

And that did submit the points eventually (after making a few adjustments to the other files obviously), But wouldn't make the other groups in the dropdown menu show up, and would just delete the whole table the checkboxes should be in.(All that appears is the dropdown menu with the previously chosen group, member names, and a whole lot of checkboxes)

Could anyone help me out? I've already been trying out solutions for 20+ hours, so I was hoping anyone has a good suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: Spend the next 20 hours on learning jQuery or another javascript framework.

Answer (score 0):

I took YOur script:
1st Output a values from DB

```
<select name="squa" id="squad">
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<option value="'.$row['squad_id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';   
  }
</select>
```

Use Ajax is not complicated:
          //when change call Ajax request

```
 $( "#squad" ).change(function() {
        var string = 'value='+$(this).val();  //value=to value of selected
        $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: string, //our value
       url:url, //where to make request
       beforeSend: function() { $('#somediv').html('Loading...'); },
       success:function(data){
          $('#somediv').html('').hide(); 
          $('#somediv').html(data); 
       },complete: function() {;
          $('#somediv').show();
        },error: function(){

    }
    });
});
```

In Url (Php file)
Make your table out:

Next file

```
$value = $_POST['value']; //GET THe value that has been choosen in select
// do whatever you want to do with this value in php and the result just

echo $result;
```

If you want to rerun an array

```
In Jquery $.ajax specify it dataTYpe:'json',
In php:
$result = array(
   'st'=>$value,
   'mp'=>$value
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

To run thorugh array in Jquery
use

```
 $('#somediv').html(data.mp+' - '+data.st);
```

And it will automatically show on the page in #somediv...

I gave an Idea try to google more about jquery it is easy when you understand it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for taking the time to help me. I'll try it out with what you suggested, and let you know if I get stuck!